# How to most efficiently keep in sync blockchain on offline computer (including through bitcoin-qt upgrades)?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, client, synchronization, offline

I have bitcoin-qt running on online computer. I want to:

1. copy blockchain to offline computer (preferably using WORM media for security reasons)
2. from time to time update offline copy with newest blocks with smallest effort. Smallest effort means - among others - that I don't want to re-record whole blockchain from online computer to media every time and would prefer incremental copy instead.

The main obstacle that I encountered until now was that - sometimes - when I updated bitcoin-qt on online computer, the 'blocks' directory was wiped out. Then whole blockchain has been re-downloaded, preventing me from copying new blocks incrementally (because for some reason new blk*.dat files had different size/content then previous).

Comment: There are wallets that explicitly support cold wallets ([example](https://www.bitcoinarmory.com/)) - maybe looking at how those work would help?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick the idea is to allow for verification of transaction history on offline computer, so cold wallet support is not enough.

Comment: Ah OK. Interesting project.